# Restricting access to particular URL for sesame server deployed on JBoss (WildFly 8.2)

Tags: jboss, wildfly, sesame

I have a sesame server running deployed in a WildFly 8.2.0 final container.

How can I restrict access to some particular URLs?

I know I have to edit some XML files (deployment descriptor and some other files) but I don't know which files and where to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out my self.

Step 1:

Open the openrdf-sesame.war with Total Commander or any file archiver. Go the WEB-INF folder and open the web.xml file.

Edit the web.xml file by adding constraints, roles and the login-config tag as in this example : http://www.rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/basic-security-with-http-authentication/

Save the edited file within the archive and redeploy the openrdf-sesame.war file containing the modified web.xml file.

Step 2:

Go to the WildFly folder and enter the bin directory and run the add-user.bat file.

Choose b) Application User and hit Enter.

Enter a username and a password for the new user.

When you are asked "What groups do you want this user to belong to?", type in one of the roles you have created in the web.xml file  and hit Enter.

When asked “is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process?” type “yes” and hit Enter.

And that's all.

You now have youre particular URL's restricted.